# Please tell me how to get the body of the sent POST request in AsyncHttpClient in the onFailure method

Tags: java, android-studio, asynchttpclient

here is an example of my code.
(Dependencies  implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.11')

```
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

asyncHttpClient.addHeader("secret", "123");

JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();

onParams.put("name", "Jon");

asyncHttpClient.post(menu.this, "http://192.168.1.104:8000/", jsonEntity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                    super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse ) {
                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                     //////////////??????????????????????????????????/////////////////////////
                }
            });
```

If the server does not respond, I get into the onFailure method with a TimeOut error, how can I get the body of my request that I sent ( onParams.put("name", "Jon");) ?

i want to get the body of the request i sent

Comment: `jsonEntity` and `onParams` are available in that scope.....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the reference from above. Also you made a little error in the second use of **jsonParams**, you typed **onParams** here.

```
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

asyncHttpClient.addHeader("secret", "123");

JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();

jsonParams.put("name", "Jon");

asyncHttpClient.post(menu.this, "http://192.168.1.104:8000/", jsonEntity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                    super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse ) {
                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                    log.d("TAG", jsonParams);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank, Yes, I apologize when I copied wrote  onParams